# What's the fastest-growing variety of cherry tree?

Tags: trees, cherries, variety-selection

I really want to add a tree to my garden, but logistics and budget demand that I plant a sapling and nurture it into a healthy tree.

I really like cherry blossom, so a cherry tree would be ideal. It's not necessary that the tree bear fruit, though that'd be a nice bonus for the local birds.

What's the fastest-growing variety of cherry tree that will give me lovely cherry blossoms? What can I do to encourage growth and keep the tree healthy?

Comment: How big do you want it to get? (height and width)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the fastest growing cherry trees is the Kanzan cherry ([*Prunus serrulata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_serrulata)) which is native to Japan, Korea and neighbouring areas. It is primarily grown as an ornamental tree all over the world for its flowers and rarely bears fruit (this is *exactly* what you want!). If you've ever seen a stock picture of a cherry blossom and thought "WoW!", then most likely, that tree was a Kanzan cherry.

[image]

It is also commonly spelled (or misspelled) as "Kwanzan", so if you're searching, you might also want to include that term. From [this website](http://www.fast-growing-trees.com/Kwanzan.htm) that sells trees, Kanzan cherry trees are

> - Hardiest of all cherry trees
> - Rapidly grows to a mature height of 30-40 ft.

It also says this about the blossoms:

> The Kwanzan Flowering Cherry Tree is
>   easily the showiest of all Cherry
>   Trees. Its flowers aren’t just pink…
>   but “Double Pink,” meaning you get
>   twice as many blooms as found on other
>   trees.

Although you haven't mentioned what climate you live in, it doesn't seem like it will be a problem, as the tree

> Thrives in almost any soil and climate. Easily grown in zones 5-9.